# Why does this ruby code related to symbols result in an infinite loop

Tags: ruby

I was trying out a ruby koan and found that this code results in an infinite loop - would appreciate some pointers on why the infinite loop happens:

```
def test_constants_become_symbols
  all_symbols_as_strings = Symbol.all_symbols.map { |x| x.to_s }

  assert_equal false, all_symbols_as_strings.include?(test_constants_become_symbols)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

This is [*infinite recursion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop#Infinite_recursion) because at this line:

```
assert_equal false, all_symbols_as_strings.include?(test_constants_become_symbols)
```

The `test_constants_become_symbols` method is called again, which runs that line *again*, and so on until the stack is too deep.

Answer (score 1):

`test_constants_become_symbols` is calling itself in the last line. There is no stop condition.

Answer (score 1):

You're recursively calling the test_constants_become_symbols function:
    assert_equal false, all_symbols_as_strings.include?**(test_constants_become_symbols)**